# using Helpintfs::IHelpSystem gives an error 'abstract class' in C++Builder

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I am using C++Builder and working with sample Delphi code for calling a new help file system called eViewer. When I convert the Delphi Procedure below the variable IHelpSystem is giving the error: variable type 'System::Helpintfs::IHelpSystem' is an abstract class. The error text is below. How can I use the variable IHelpSystem and the function GetHelpSystem in C++Builder?

```
//Original Delphi
procedure TFrmHelpViewerMain.btnShowTopicClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  HelpSystem: IHelpSystem;
begin
  GetHelpSystem(HelpSystem);
  if assigned(HelpSystem) then
    HelpSystem.ShowTopicHelp('topic3', Application.HelpFile);
 end;


//My C++Builder code
#include <System.HelpIntfs.hpp>
void __fastcall TForm99::btnShowTopicClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  IHelpSystem HelpSystem; //<< Error Here

  GetHelpSystem(HelpSystem);

  if( Assigned(HelpSystem) ){
    HelpSystem->ShowTopicHelp("topic3", Application->HelpFile);
  }
}
```

[bcc64 Error] CBtest_Unit1.cpp(97): variable type 'System::Helpintfs::IHelpSystem' is an abstract class

- unknwn.h(114): unimplemented pure virtual method 'QueryInterface' in 'IHelpSystem'
- unknwn.h(118): unimplemented pure virtual method 'AddRef' in 'IHelpSystem'
- unknwn.h(120): unimplemented pure virtual method 'Release' in 'IHelpSystem'
- System.HelpIntfs.hpp(66): unimplemented pure virtual method 'ShowHelp' in 'IHelpSystem'
- System.HelpIntfs.hpp(67): unimplemented pure virtual method 'ShowContextHelp' in 'IHelpSystem'
- System.HelpIntfs.hpp(68): unimplemented pure virtual method 'ShowTableOfContents' in 'IHelpSystem'
- System.HelpIntfs.hpp(69): unimplemented pure virtual method 'ShowTopicHelp' in 'IHelpSystem'
- System.HelpIntfs.hpp(70): unimplemented pure virtual method 'AssignHelpSelector' in 'IHelpSystem'
- System.HelpIntfs.hpp(71): unimplemented pure virtual method 'Hook' in 'IHelpSystem'

Here are the help pages from the Embaradero website that discuss IHelpSystem.

[IHelpSystem](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.HelpIntfs)

[HelpIntfs.GetHelpSystem](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.HelpIntfs.GetHelpSystem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, [`IHelpSystem`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.HelpIntfs.IHelpSystem) is an abstract class (it has pure virtual methods that are implemented in derived classes), and as such you can't instantiate it directly, like you are trying to do in your C++ code:

```cpp
IHelpSystem HelpSystem;
```

You can declare variables of this type only by pointer (`IHelpSystem*`) or reference (`IHelpSystem&`). And indeed, the C++ equivalent of the Delphi statement:

```pascal
var HelpSystem: IHelpSystem;
```

is:

```cpp
IHelpSystem* HelpSystem;
```

But, since `IHelpSystem` is a Delphi-based interface, you actually need to use the `_di_IHelpSystem` wrapper type (which is an alias for [`DelphiInterface<IHelpSystem>`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DelphiInterface)), which is what [`GetHelpSystem()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.HelpIntfs.GetHelpSystem) actually outputs in C++:

```cpp
extern DELPHI_PACKAGE bool __fastcall GetHelpSystem(/* out */ _di_IHelpSystem &System)/* overload */;
```

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <System.HelpIntfs.hpp>

void __fastcall TForm99::btnShowTopicClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    _di_IHelpSystem HelpSystem;
    GetHelpSystem(HelpSystem);
    if (HelpSystem)
        HelpSystem->ShowTopicHelp(_D("topic3"), Application->HelpFile);
}
```